Why is a NEXT_REDIRECT error being thrown in next-auth sign in
I am writing a login feature using next.js, next-auth, prisma, postgres and react server components. I get a NEXT_REDIRECT error whenever a user logs in, which does not cause an issue during development but breaks the deployed version. Here is the server component and the login form page:
"use server";

import { DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT } from "@/route";
import { signIn } from "@/server/auth";
import { db } from "@/server/db";
import { LoginSchema } from "@/utils/validators/user";
import { AuthError } from "next-auth";
import { z } from "zod";

export const login = async (
  values: z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>,
  callbackUrl?: string | null,
) => {
  const validateFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(values);

  if (!validateFields.success) {
    return { error: "Invalid fields." };
  }

  const { email, password } = validateFields.data;

  const existingUser = await db.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      email,
    },
  });

  if (!existingUser?.email || !existingUser?.password) {
    return { error: "Invalid credentials. Please try again." };
  }

  try {
    await signIn("credentials", {
      email,
      password,
      redirectTo: callbackUrl ?? DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AuthError) {
      switch (error.type) {
        case "CredentialsSignin":
          return { error: "Invalid credentials. Please try again." };
        default:
          return { error: "Something went wrong. Please try again." };
      }
    }

    throw error;
  }
};

"use client";

import { z } from "zod";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { CardWrapper } from "@/components/auth/card-wrapper";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { LoginSchema } from "@/utils/validators/user";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";
import { Input } from "../ui/input";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useTransition, useState } from "react";
import { login } from "@/actions/login";
import { FormError } from "@/components/misc/form-error";
import { FormSuccess } from "@/components/misc/form-success";

export const LoginForm = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const callbackUrl = searchParams.get("callbackUrl");
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | undefined>("");
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState<string | undefined>("");
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(LoginSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = (values: z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>) => {
    setError("");
    setSuccess("");

    startTransition(() => {
      login(values, callbackUrl)
        .then((data) => {
          if (data?.error) {
            form.reset();
            setError(data.error);
          }

          form.reset();
          setSuccess("User logged in successfully.");
        })
        .catch(() => {
          setError("Something went wrong!");
        });
    });
  };

  return (
    <CardWrapper
      headerLabel="Welcome Back"
      backButtonLabel="Don't have an account?"
      backButtonHref="/auth/register"
    >
      <Form {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-6">
          <div className="space-y-4">
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="email"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      {...field}
                      disabled={isPending}
                      placeholder="john.doe@example.com"
                      type="email"
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="password"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      {...field}
                      disabled={isPending}
                      placeholder="P@ssw0rd"
                      type="password"
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
          </div>
          <FormError message={error} />
          <FormSuccess message={success} />
          <Button disabled={isPending} type="submit" className="w-full">
            Login
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Form>
    </CardWrapper>
  );
};

I have tried some solutions from the web that did not help. I need help on how to deal with this error.
